# Retrieve related data-set on Phalcon

Tags: mysql, orm, phalcon, relation

I have two tables. Which I wanted to return not only the parent data "Lists", but including the relationship to "ListTypes". How can I do that?

> $d = self::find(); // WORKS - but missing relations, see expected result.

**Tables:**

1. Lists
2. List Types

**With the following code relations.**

```
// Models/Lists.php
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Lists extends Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('type_id', 'ListTypes', 'id');
    }

    public function getData() {
        $d = self::find();
    }
}
?>

// Models/ListTypes.php
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class ListTypes extends Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('id', 'Lists', 'type_id');
    }
}
?>
```

**Current results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Airbus
            [type_id] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => BMW
            [type_id] => 2
        )
)
```

**Expected results:** -- I want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Airbus
            [type_id] => 1
            [type_name] => Airplane
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => BMW
            [type_id] => 2
            [type_name] => Car
        )
)
```

Comment: Bummer! As of today, I think the best answer would be. https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2104/related-records-automatically-including

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function that will get the related models for you as long as you set an alias for the child relation inside every parent model.
[PHP / Phalcon - Automatically nesting objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124423/php-phalcon-automatically-nesting-objects/30591448#30591448)